# JWT session extends after the first 20 minutes but timeout after 1 hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwt

I have a JWT session that asks user to extend the session every 20 minutes if the user is not doing anything on the site. BUT the session expires after 1 hour regardless whether the user is actively working on the site or not. Is there any way to prevent that? I have codes below that implement JWT, but due to the amount of codes I can't able to include all the codebase, but thought this may be enough to start.

AuthorizationHelper:

```
def authorize_request_and_set_current_user
    request.headers["X-CSRF-Token"] = request.cookies["csrf_token"]
    set_current_user
  end

  # This sets the user session by senting the JWT cookie to the user's browser
  def set_user(user)
    payload  = {
      user_id: user.id
    }
    session = JWTSessions::Session.new(payload: payload, refresh_by_access_allowed: true)
    tokens = session.login
    response.set_cookie(
      cookies.permanent[JWTSessions.access_cookie] = secure_cookie_for(value: tokens[:access]),
      cookies.permanent['csrf_token'] = secure_cookie_for(value: tokens[:csrf])
    )
    
    @current_user = user
    user.record_session_id(nil)
    user.after_login
  end
```

exception_methods: This method renders a modal that jumps in the middle of page and ask user to login after 1 hour while user is using the website:

```
def not_authorized
    flash[:error] = 'Please login in order to continue.'
    redirect_to login_path
end
```

I can provide more code snippets if requested, but can something be done on JWT implementation to refresh the session while user is actively working on the site and not being kicked out after one hour?

Comment: You can add tokens api, on refresh call tokens api and use that token for next request, like wise your session will be alive untill user is actively using application.

Comment: Thank you for your response. To elaborate this, would you mean  adding a refresh token inside the response.set_cookie?
something like this?

cookies.permanent[JWTSessions.access_cookie] = secure_cookie_for(value: tokens[:refresh])